# Codeigniter 2.1, MySQL - two left joins

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have query like this:

```
$q = " SELECT C.*, count(K.id_komentar) broj_komentara FROM clanak C
        LEFT JOIN kategorija KAT
            ON C.kategorija_id = KAT.id_kategorija
        LEFT JOIN komentari K
            ON C.id_clanak = K.clanak_id
        GROUP BY C.id_clanak
        ORDER BY datum_kreiranja DESC ";
  return  $this->db->query($q)->result_array();
```

Count part is working, but first **LEFT JOIN** (with **kategorija**) is not working. I am not getting anything from from table **kategorija**. How can I join table **kategorija** and get data from that table?

**EDIT (tables)**

```
kategorija
    id_kategorija
    naziv
    word

clanak
    id_clanal
    naslov
    opis
    kategorija_id
    autor

komentari
    id_komentar
    clanak_id
    tekst
```

Comment: first, who is kate gorija?

Comment: please could you provide any sample data or better an sqlfiddle?

Comment: I think you are just selecting C - clanak and your count, not KAT - kategorija

Comment: @LuigiSiri That's seems to be a problem. I though that it will automatically select all from **kategorija** table, but I was wrong. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @Sasha, you are welcome. So, I will write my comment as an answer then...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are just selecting C - clanak and your count, not KAT - kategorija.

So, it would be something like this:

```
SELECT KAT.*, C.*, count(K.id_komentar) broj_komentara FROM...
```